# How to use Docker local-persist plugin as a systemd service on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: docker, docker-compose, plugins

I'm trying to create persistent docker volumes for a large application consisting of several dozen services (and around 35 volumes.) I came across the `local-persist` plugin at the [Use Docker Engine Plugins page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/legacy_plugins/) on the Docker website. I followed the [author's README](https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist) to install `local-persist` as a systemd service. Essentially:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CWSpear/local-persist/master/scripts/install.sh | sudo bash
```

The service has been installed and is running correctly on each node:

```bash
$ systemctl | grep pers
  docker-volume-local-persist.service       loaded active running   docker-volume-local-persist
$
```

But when I try to use it from a `docker-compose` file (author instructions [here](https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist/blob/master/docker-compose.example.yml), referenced in the README):

```yaml
volumes:
  cache-perstnt-1-data:
    driver: local-persist
    driver_opts:
      mountpoint: /data/cache-perstnt-1-data
```

...Docker can't find the plugin.

Is there something else I need to do to let Docker know the plugin's available as a systemd service?